# Monit background script running within a detached screen

Tags: monit, gnu-screen

How can Monit be used to monitor a simple script that creates no PID file and is running in the background within a detached screen session?

Answer (score 0):

See [Documentation regarding CHECK PROCESS](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Process). It's as simple as

```
CHECK PROCESS myProcName MATCHING "my_detached_script.sh"
```

It checks for Processes containing "my_detached_script.sh" (note: It's a regex. So it also matches "my_detached_script-sh" and so on). It can be any valid regex. You might want to check your regex with `monit procmatch '<YourRegexHere>'` to match your needs.